# Ubuntu super-key doesn't work properly because of Tweaks

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys

So, to keep it short, I am using Unbuntu 19.04 with Gnome and the Tweaks-Program (which I would like to keep using), but the latter has created (that is I believe it is the cause) an issue for me:

Everytime I restart my computer, the Super+Num shortcuts won't work, where num is any number between 1-9 (actually, it always works for some arbitrary numbers, but not for others)

Then, when I go into tweaks -> Keyboard & Mouse, and change "Overview-Sortcut" from Left to Right and then back from Right to Left, everything works fine again.

What can I do to prevent this issue? Disabling some "feature" in Tweaks which is responsible for this behavior comes to mind, but I have no idea how.

Comment: Does this occur with the current 19.10 version? We lose support for 19.04 next month...

Comment: This is not caused by Tweaks. Are you using any third party extension (Gnome Shell extensions website)? If yes, then look for the culprit there. You happen to use the Arc menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to disable the following extension:
[image: Block Caribou Extension]

Had it turned on, since I never use the (quite lousy) touchscreen on my Thinkpad, but I guess I can live without it.